# Snap in capacitor in place of through hole

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, analog, audio, vintage

I have an old Technics SU-V5 amplifier from 1980.  It has through hole capacitors with very thin legs.  All new capacitors are snap in and their legs are very thick.  They won't fit in the PCB.  How do people replace capacitors in such an event?

[image: my old capacitor1]

[image: new]

Comment: _All new capacitors are snap in_ - Uh what? That's news to me. Several thousand vendor results as well as most PCBs I own say otherwise.

Comment: Just buy the right capacitor. When you need new tyres for your V8 car, what do you check?

Comment: I've run into this many times.    Just take a good cutter and trim the pins down enough to fit in the PCB.  Be careful not to stress the mechanical connections.

Comment: No all the big capacities are snap in I found 8200 63V, 10000 63V all snap in. I think I'm gonna try to trim the pins down thanks.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt t the first picture it radial lead, not axial.

Comment: Drill holes in the pcb to suit. The pcb is usually single sided so its not much of a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There will be little difference between the two, if they fit mechanically then you could solder the snap in capacitor. The most important thing is to match the ESR, and make sure the voltage rating meets or exceeds that of the "old" capacitor. The last thing is if the capacitor is a bypass capacitor, then it needs to have a capacity greater than that of the old capacitor.

If the capacitor is used for filtering, then the value must be matched.

The new capacitor only goes to 50V on it's rating, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

On a single sided pcb, with non plated through holes, if the pads are large enough you can simply drill to enlarge the holes a bit.

Make sure you drill from the copper side then through the PCB, not the other way around, as that could lift the pads out from the pcb.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me once. The spacing was ok, but the legs were too think. It was not 1 layer PCB (so no drilling) and did not want to mount anything to the cap lead (the circuit was visible behind plexiglass).

I just filed some material off.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with my Carvin SX-200 amp. The only audio rated good quality caps I could find were snap-ins and the lead diameter and spacing were different. I wound up mounting the pair of large caps off-board to the back of my amp using 22mm p-clamps. I soldered wires to the snap-in leads on the caps and shrink tubed them for safety, then just soldered the wires in the holes on the board. Doesn't look too bad and on a positive note they will be easier to replace in the future.

Comment: Okay, you poked my curiosity; What properties does an "audio-rated high quality cap" have that excludes almost every other cap on the marked? Due to demands for reliability on the products I have made, I have used nothing but the top-tier quality electrolytes the last decade. I have never had an issue finding leaded caps. I know some of them come in a snap-in package (as I have a bag of some due to ordering the incorrect partnumer) but I have never been *forced* to use snap-in leads.

Comment: When I have used general purpose caps in an audio application I wound up with mixed results and usually noise in the output. I look at the data sheet from the manufacturer and when they state it is intended for audio or communications equipment it works, so that is what I buy. The wrong cap in your guitar amp will have a significant effect on the sound of your amp. In this case I was looking for a pair of 4700uF 50v electrolytic caps for an amp built in the early '90s, the original caps are no longer made and I could only find audio caps from Nichicon.